# Air Native Extensions: How to allocate a ByteArray and manage its memory?

Tags: air, air-native-extension

I am thinking of writing a C-based ANE to speed up a critical section of my application. It should receive a ByteArray with data, do some processing, and return a different ByteArray.

The output ByteArray would be created (and malloc'd) by the C side of my ANE. My questions are:

Is it possible to do this and how? (the example in the Adobe site is quite poor; it just modifies an input ByteArray, without even changing its size)

If I managed to do so, would the AS side then be the one responsible for releasing the memory of the returned object through normal garbage collection?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to pass in an empty `ByteArray` on the AS3 side and manipulate the object on the C side.

You can't return a `ByteArray` (or `BitmapData` for that matter) from the C side because it exists on the C side as a `struct` which isn't compatible with the `FREObject` the API expects you to return.